# Python 2.7 threading queue, reuse threads

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am looking for a way to have a background thread queue run for an unlimited amount of times. The code below is what I came up with from research, but I am being limited to the amount of threads I create.
On my research I have not been able to figure out a way to just have 1 or 2 threads always available, and running a set function when I add it to the queue.

Goal of this sample app is to check the status of a site every 10 seconds, if the response code is not 200, run the code in the notify function.

What is happening now is the code is working correctly up until I hit the limit of threads I created, 5 in this case. The main while loop keeps working correctly, but the code that needs to execute when there is a failure stops because there are no more threads.

```
import urllib2, time
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

# Set up global variables
num_threads = 5
queue = Queue()
urlList = [
    "http://google.com",
    "http://googleeeeeee1111.com"
]


def notify(i, q):
    print "Thread %s: started" % i
    url = q.get()
    print "Thread %s: notification sent for site: %s" % (i, url)
    q.task_done()


def make_requests():
    while True:
        for url in urlList:
            try:
                request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
                responseCode = request.getcode()

                # If the response code was 200, do something
                if responseCode == 200:
                    print "URL: %s  -  Success %d" % (url, responseCode)
                else:
                    print "Bad response code for %s  -  %d " % (url, responseCode)
                    queue.put(url)

            except Exception, e:
                print "ERROR MAKING REQUEST TO %s - %s" % (url, e)
                queue.put(url)
        time.sleep(10)  # wait 10 seconds and start again


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up some threads to fetch the enclosures
    for i in range(num_threads):
        worker = Thread(target=notify, args=(i, queue, ))
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()

    make_requests()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting here's the documentation of [Python's GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) and how it is affecting threads.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could wrap `notify` into a never ending loop. I modified your code in order to act like that, + some small corrections that don't have very much to do with the functionality:

```
import urllib2, time
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

# Set up global variables
num_threads = 3 #you can set it to any number of threads (although 1 would be enough)

queue = Queue()
url_list = [
    "http://google.com",
    "http://googleeeeeee1111.com"
]


def notify(i, q):
    url = q.get()
    print "Thread %d: notification sent for site: %s" % (i, url)
    q.task_done()


def thread_func(i, q):
    print "Thread %d: started" % i
    while True:
        notify(i, q)
    print "Thread %d: ending" % i

def make_requests():
    while True:
        for url in url_list:
            try:
                request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
                response_code = request.getcode()

                # If the response code was 200, do something
                if response_code == 200:
                    print "URL: %s  -  Success %d" % (url, response_code)
                else:
                    print "Bad response code for %s  -  %d " % (url, response_code)
                    queue.put(url)

            except Exception as e:
                print "ERROR MAKING REQUEST TO %s - %s" % (url, e)
                queue.put(url)
        time.sleep(10)  # wait 10 seconds and start again


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set up some threads to fetch the enclosures
    for i in xrange(num_threads):
        worker = Thread(target=thread_func, args=(i, queue))
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()

    make_requests()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs. I need play a little more with this code to understand how the infinite loop for the notify function is fixing the issue

Comment: In the original implementation, each thread was taking __one__ URL from the queue, processed it and then ended. That's why only `num_threads` messages were processed from the queue (after all the threads ended there was no one to process the URLS that `make_requests` was continuously adding to the queue). Now, each thread gets one message from the queue, processes it, but instead of ending, it waits (indefinitely) for another URL to be pushed in the queue, and when the new URL is in the queue, it process it too, and so on....